# Stream Html document in a new page ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, actionresult

I have an object Document that describes a file: the file is HTML format file.

```
public class FileObj
{
    public string FileName;
    public string MimeType;
    public Stream File;
}
```

This is my controller Action

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Open(Guid fileId)
{
    var document = repository.GetFile(fileId);
    return File(document.File, document.MimeType, document.FileName);
}
```

In the view there is a simple link like this:

```
<a href="/Documents/Open?fileId=1" target="blank" title="Click to download">open file</a>
```

Every time I click the link the file is downloaded. 
I want it to be opened by the browser in a new window instead.

How can I do it? I am working in ASP.NET MVC3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify a `Content-Disposition` header:

```
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + document.FileName);
return File(document.File, document.MimeType);
```

Also, I think you're looking for `target="_blank"`. The attribute `target="blank"` will open in a window/tab named internally as "blank", and any further clicks will reload that window/tab instead of popping a new window/tab each time.

Comment: Thanks Chris, if I do this I get an error in Chrome "Duplicate headers received from server"

Comment: Sorry. Passing the third param for filename, automatically sets a `Content-Disposition` header as `attachment`. Just remove that param. For reference see the "Remarks" section of http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492593(v=vs.118).aspx. It's also possible you don't need to add the response header manually at that point, either, since the default disposition should be "inline". But, if you want to specify the filename should the user choose to download it after view it, you'll still need to add the header manually.